# How do you check for sanity in objective-c and cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

What is the preferred method of checking for sanity in objective-c and cocoa?

Comment: @Chuck I've seen a lot of different styles of checking and bailing. What's yours?

Comment: @Joe - Same... some assert, others check a call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Near the top of a method, `NSParameterAssert` that necessary objects are not `nil`, indexes are in range, etc. Sometimes you can get these for free; for example, an indexed accessor backed by an array can let the underlying array do the asserting for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSAssert(thisShouldBeTrue, @"Error message");
```